# Dynamic Masonry Gallery using JavaScript and Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I wanna create a gallery full responsive and dynamic like this: https://www.pixelflakes.com/work/

Where I should start looking for some good stuff to really understand how to create this? I'm a beginner at JavaScript, but I'm pretty good at html, CSS and bootstrap.

thanks for the help!

Comment: You can try creating the layout since you are already aware of html,css and bootstrap

Comment: visit this [link](http://www.menucool.com/ui/responsive-image-grid-with-hover-effect)

Answer (score 0):

I came across a [demo](https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/pinterest-like-responsive-grid) that might help you understand how to create a gallery like that. Also [mensonry's codebase](https://github.com/desandro/masonry) is available on Github. Considering that you're new to javascript, it might take some time to grasp but you'll be alright after putting in some effort.